# How do I change color of arrow on product detail page

Tags: magento-2.1

I need to change the color of the arrow on the product detail page.

I think that arrow is not an image.

[image]

Comment: if possible, post the link of the site, so that it will be better to help....

Comment: This is visible on my default magento 2.1.9 install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are 2 options to to this, either you change this using css(less) or by changing sprite image file.

Sprite image file :
This arrow is coming from gallery sprite image (gallery.png).
you can find it here magento-root/lib/web/mage/gallery/gallery.png

Less file location :
magento-root/lib/web/mage/gallery/gallery.less